Generate property names from string paths, with special handling for duplicate segments
I have a permissions hook that needs to generate property keys based on permission strings. The tricky part is handling duplicate segments:
For unique segments like Company.SendInvitation, it correctly generates isSendInvitationEnabled
But for duplicates like ["Company.Users.View", "System.Users.View"], it should generate:

isCompanyUsersViewEnabled
isSystemUsersViewEnabled

Current types only generate isUsersViewEnabled for both. Here's the type setup:
type ExtractPermissionName<T> = T extends `${string}.${infer R}`
  ? R extends `${infer F}.${infer Rest}`
    ? `${Capitalize<F>}${ExtractPermissionName<Rest>}`
    : Capitalize<R>
  : T

The implementation correctly handles this by checking for duplicates, but the types don't reflect it. Any ideas how to modify ExtractPermissionName to consider the full path when there are duplicate last segments?
type AllPermissions = "Company.SendInvitation" | "Company.Users.View" | "Platform.Users.View";

type PermissionOptions<P extends string = string, S extends string = string> = {
  prefix: P;
  suffix: S;
};

type ExtractPermissionName<T> = T extends `${string}.${infer R}`
  ? R extends `${infer F}.${infer Rest}`
    ? `${Capitalize<F>}${ExtractPermissionName<Rest>}`
    : Capitalize<R>
  : T;

type PermissionKey<
  P extends string,
  O extends Partial<PermissionOptions> = { prefix: "is"; suffix: "Enabled" }
> = `${O["prefix"] extends string ? O["prefix"] : "is"}${ExtractPermissionName<P>}${
  O["suffix"] extends string ? O["suffix"] : "Enabled"
}`;

const usePermissions = <P extends AllPermissions | AllPermissions[]>(
  permissions: P) => {
  const perms: AllPermissions[] = Array.isArray(permissions) ? permissions : [permissions];
  
  return perms.reduce((acc, perm) => {
    const key = `is${perm.split(".").slice(1).map(s => 
      s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)).join("")}Enabled`;
    return { ...acc, [key]: true };
  }, {}) as Record<PermissionKey<P extends AllPermissions[] ? P[number] : P>, boolean>;
};

// Example usage:
const single = usePermissions("Company.Users.View");
// Type: { isUsersViewEnabled: boolean }

const multiple = usePermissions(["Company.Users.View", "Company.SendInvitation"]);
// Type: { isUsersViewEnabled: boolean; isSendInvitationEnabled: boolean }

const custom = usePermissions(["Platform.Users.View", "Company.Users.View"]);
// Type: { isUsersViewEnabled: boolean }
// It must be two not one: 
// { isPlatformUsersViewEnabled: boolean }, { isCompanyUsersViewEnabled: boolean }


Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] where the only problems present in the code are what you're asking about (so no missing declarations or references to private or third party types or values) and where your problem is clearly demonstrated. It sounds like the example really should be a bunch of desired input-ouput pairs that demonstrate the range of the issue to be solved.

sure, just updated it @jcalz thanks

What does canUsersListPermission mean in your expected output?

it was a type, just updated it

You're always discarding the first segment in ExtractPermissionName.  So "Company" and "System" are discarded.

This playground shows a simple modification made to ExtractPermissionName.  This solves the issue.  However, it changes your "correct" isSendInvitationEnabled to isCompanySendInvitationEnabled.

Do you need this to work for arbitrarily long paths? If so, look at this playground link. (Note that it produces isViewEnabled for "Company.Users.View" for the same reason isSendInvitationEnabled is produced for "Company.SendInvitation"; it's only taking the rightmost chunk that it needs. I have no idea why you'd want isUsersViewEnabled for "Company.Users.View". Why preserve "Users"?) If this is what you want I could write an answer explaining it, but it's complicated, because it has to keep checking for duplicates at each stage. If not, what's missing?

(see prev comment) I'm still finding myself confused about what you're doing. Maybe you could reduce this to a [mre] where you don't care about capitalization (you can surely handle that yourself) or a particular implementation (so we can focus on types) and just give us a list of input/output types and the motivation behind them.

(see prev comments) Even the is+Enabled part is a complication we don't need.  I'm reading into this that you want ["Aa.Bb", "Cc.Dd"] to become ["Bb", "Dd"] but ["Aa.Bb", "Cc.Bb"] to become ["AaBb", "CcDd"]. That is, you want to handle duplicates in the actual input and not duplicates in all possible inputs. I'd really recommend [edit]ing the question to make it as clear and concise as possible. Otherwise you're going to get answers that provide what they guess you want, instead of what is clearly stated in the question.

Each argument we pass as an array to usePermissions contains segments separated by . (dot) For instance: ["Platform.Users.View", "Company.Users.View"]. In this input, the last two segments are the same: Platform.Users.View and Company.Users.View. In this case, the function should return the following results:

isCompanyUsersView
isPlatformUsersView
@jcalz


You've explained the only part of this I understand. Please look at the playground link above, re-read my previous comments, and consider [edit]ing the question to address them. I'm happy to give further advice and ask more questions, but I don't want to repeat myself.

The only problem you got your string parsing wrong, use better:
type IsUnion<T, C extends T = T> = (T extends T ? C extends T ? true : unknown : never) extends true ? false : true;
type GetGroup<T> = T extends `${infer A}.${string}` ? A : never;
type ExtractPart<T, NoSkipGroup = true> = T extends `${infer A}.${infer B}` ? `${NoSkipGroup extends true ? Capitalize<A> : ''}${ExtractPart<B>}` : T;
type ExtractPermissionName<T> = ExtractPart<T, IsUnion<GetGroup<T>>>;


Playground

If you try to destructure custom you will get my point. custom has to have both isPlatformUsersViewEnabled and isCompanyUsersViewEnabled

@SirwanAfifi fixed

thanks, it has one edge case, when we add usePermissions(["Company.SendInvitation",  "Platform.Module.B",   "Feature.Module.A"]) it generates isCompanySendInvitationEnabled, isFeatureModuleAEnabled, isPlatformModuleBEnabled instead of isSendInvitationEnabled, isModuleAEnabled, isModuleBEnabled

@SirwanAfifi what's logic behinds this ? you said you need { isPlatformUsersViewEnabled: boolean }, { isCompanyUsersViewEnabled: boolean } and now this, seems completely different approach

Initially, I want to use two segments. For example, in cases like ["Platform.Users.View", "Company.Users.View"], when there are duplicate segments (the last two segments: .Users.View), we should use all three segments to differentiate them. Otherwise, two segments are sufficient because the values in the array are unique. If we only use two segments for ["Platform.Users.View", "Company.Users.View"], there is no way to determine which permission corresponds to isUsersEnabled. Because both permissions would map to the same key.
